# action.payload is returning undefined when I use createAsyncThunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm new to using Redux/Redux-Toolkit and I've been trying to fetch some data using the createAsyncThunk method that RTK provides to asynchronous methods but I've been running into problems where on 'fullfilled' my payload just returns null.

I was also able to console.log the data I fetched just for test purposes, so I know that I'm able to fetch it.

Im not sure if this is a javascript issue I'm having or a Redux issue, so any help is appreciated!

Heres some snippets of the code I have if anyone is interested in helping!

```js
// searchSlice.js

const fetchRequest = () => {
  return fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(client_id + ':' + client_secret),
    },
    body: 'grant_type=client_credentials',
  })
}
```

```js
// searchSlice.js

export const getArtistByQuery = createAsyncThunk('search/getArtistByQuery', async (query) => {
    await fetchRequest()
        .then((result) => result.json())
        .then((data) => {
          const token = data?.access_token;
          const spotify = new SpotifyWebApi();
    
          spotify.setAccessToken(token);
          spotify.searchArtists(query, {limit: 10})
          .then((data) => {
            return data?.artists?.items
          })
        })
})
```

```js
// Where I dispatch 
// SearchInput.js

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(getArtistByQuery(query));
    console.log(artists);
    setQuery("");
  }

  return (
    <Flex textAlign="center" m={5}>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <FormControl>
                <Input mb={5} type="text" onChange={handleChange} placeholder='Enter artist' size="md"/>
                <Button type="submit">Click Me</Button>
            </FormControl>
        </form>
    </Flex>
  )
}
```

```js
// createSlice

const artistsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'artists',
    initialState,
    extraReducers: builder => {
      builder.addCase(getArtistByQuery.pending, state => {
        state.loading = true
      })
      builder.addCase(getArtistByQuery.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false
        console.log("Payload: " + action.payload)
        state.artists = action.payload
        state.error = ''
      })
      builder.addCase(getArtistByQuery.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false
        state.artists = {}
        state.error = action.error.message
      })
    }
    })
```

```js
// initialState

const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    artists: {},
    error: ''
}
```

```js
// store.js

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    artistsSlice: artistReducer,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of this

```
export const getArtistByQuery = 
   createAsyncThunk('search/getArtistByQuery', async (query) => {
      await fetchRequest().then
```

should be this

```
export const getArtistByQuery = 
   createAsyncThunk('search/getArtistByQuery', async (query) => {
      return await fetchRequest().then()
```

Comment: I see. I just tried adding returns but my `artists` array is still null. This was what I wrote
`
await fetchRequest()
        .then((result) => {return result.json()})
        .then((data) => {
          const token = data?.access_token;
          const spotify = new SpotifyWebApi();
    
          spotify.setAccessToken(token);
          return spotify.searchArtists(query, {limit: 10})
          .then((data) => {
            return data?.artists?.items
          })
        })
`

Comment: check what `spotify.searchArtists(query, {limit: 10})` returning.

Comment: also you might use `await` when using `spotify`.  check its docs

Comment: Is the 3rd then for  `searchArtists`

Comment: Okay so im able to console my token, and I can also console `data?.artists?.items`. But redux doesn't seem to update the state

Comment: can you paste the slicer where you used `getArtistByQuery`

Comment: const artistsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'artists',
    initialState,
    extraReducers: builder => {
      builder.addCase(getArtistByQuery.pending, state => {
        state.loading = true
      })
      builder.addCase(getArtistByQuery.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false
        state.artists = action.payload
        state.error = ''
      })
      builder.addCase(getArtistByQuery.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false
        state.artists = {}
        state.error = action.error.message
      })
    }
    })

Comment: My initial state value: 
const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    artists: {},
    error: ''
}

Comment: can you nicely paste on the question pls.

Comment: Sorry @Yilmaz , just updated my question with the code snippet.